# RMarkdown pdf - Font color

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

How can I change the font color in RMarkdown pdf output.
I did try doing, Roses are \textcolor{red}{red}, violets are \textcolor{blue}{blue}.
But this only worked for the very first line in the pdf document. Upon using the same subsequently, it outputs this error,

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> /tmp/tex2pdf.18828/input.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/tex2pdf.18828/input.log.

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

Help appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: At other times, it produces this error

Comment: output file: GWAS_Data_Cleaning.knit.md

! Paragraph ended before \@textcolor was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.771 

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted